# Cloning while providing arguments for construction function

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, constructor, clone

I am trying to clone my contract by using [Clones.sol](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy#Clones) from OpenZeppelin. The cloning procedure is successful, although I cannot pass them my desired arguments which should be provided for construction function.

Does anyone know how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal.

A deployed smart contract runtime bytecode does not include constructor code (see the [constructor caveat](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies#the-constructor-caveat)).

> In Solidity, code that is inside a constructor or part of a global
> variable declaration is not part of a deployed contract’s runtime
> bytecode. This code is executed only once, when the contract instance
> is deployed. As a consequence of this, the code within a logic
> contract’s constructor will never be executed in the context of the
> proxy’s state. To rephrase, proxies are completely oblivious to the
> existence of constructors. It’s simply as if they weren’t there for
> the proxy.

Therefore, you cannot pass any parameters to a constructor, as there is no constructor when you use clone.

What you need to do is use an initializer like in the link that I mentioned above **and call that initializer just after cloning.** Basically, your constructor becomes the initializer function.

Switch to [openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable) for your clonable implementations. And make use of the [initializer modifier](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol) to protect your "constructor".

Comment: Could you please why I have to use upgradeable contracts?

Comment: It's simply that the constructor logic is already implemented as initializer functions in the upgradeable contracts. So no need for you to reimplement a constructor logic in your cloneable contracts as it's already done (and very well tested !). See for yourself : ERC20(https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L54)  vs UpgradeableERC20 (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol#L55). But if you do not use any openzeppelin logic for those, then no need.